# Error with swig: undefined symbol: _ZN7hosters11hostersLink7getLinkEi

Tags: c++, swig, undefined-symbol

I'm trying to make a python binding for the this library:

http://code.google.com/p/hosterslib/.

I'm using swig, heres is the code:

```
%module pyhosters    
%{    
#include "hosters/hosters.hpp"    
%}    
%include "hosters/hosters.hpp"
```

I run

> swig -c++ -python -o swig_wrap.cxx swig.i

and I compile with

> g++ -O2 -fPIC -shared -o _pyhosters.so swig_wrap.cxx `python-config --libs --cflags` -lhosters -lcln -lhtmlcxx `pkg-config libglog --libs --cflags` -I/usr/include/python2.6 -Wall -Wextra

But when I run python and I import it, I get:

```
>>> import pyhosters    
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>    
  File "./pyhosters.py", line 7, in <module>    
    import _pyhosters    
ImportError: ./_pyhosters.so: undefined symbol: _ZN7hosters11hostersLink7getLinkEi
```

How can I solve that?

Thanks.

Comment: Use markup (read the help if neccessary) and check how the question looks in the preview before posting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the mangled name of:

```
hosters::hostersLink::getLink(int)
```

Make sure you have defined that function.

Okay, I took a closer look at hosters 0.6.  The header files declares two `getLink` methods:

```
std::string getLink(void);
std::string getLink(int n);
```

But the source file only declares the first one:

```
std::string hostersLink::getLink(void) {return Link;}
```

But SWIG is creating wrappers for both of those functions which screws things up.  I recommend doing one of two things:

1. Delete the `std::string getLink(int n);` method as it's undefined.
2. Add a definition for `std::string getLink(int n) { ... }`

Comment: Yes, it should be defined with the option "-lhosters".

Comment: @Eduardo - it *should* but it's **not** defining it.  I've included more information.

Comment: Thank you, I declared the second one accidentaly, thank you for taking your time.